# Synchronous jsroute call

Tags: ajax, playframework-2.0, synchronous

How to make a synchronous call using play framework JSRoute

`jsRoutes.controllers.Controller_name.function_name().ajax({
 //ajax handlers here
});`

Want this call to execute and fetch data before proceeding to rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Its a really bad idea (tm) but if you really want to do it you should be able to do it by providing the async property in the parameter to ajax:

```
var result = null;
jsRoutes.controllers.Controller_name.function_name().ajax({
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    result = data;
  }
});
// won't continue here until response is processed
```